# Unit test in Python, error in setup class

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am writing a test suite as:

```
class MySuite(unnitest.Testcase):

@classmethod
def setUpclass(cls):
    try:
        ***some code which will throw exception***
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error Thrown')
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    print('In teardown')
def test_demo(self):
    print('In test_demo')
```

The problem is, though error will be thrown in setup (*because of 5/0*), the test_demo will be executed, which I do not want to.

What could be the best approach to stop executing the test_demo whenever there is an error in setup method.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `try-except` in your setup, and just allow the exception to propagate?

Answer (score 1):

You're catching the error and just printing a message in response. Don't do that.

If you really want to print something, at least re-raise the exception afterwards. But better not to bother catching it at all: the traceback should be sufficient information.

(Also, the first parameter to a classmethod is usually called `cls` not `self`, as it is the class itself.)